# Error when installing visual studio 2005 on vista

Tags: visual-studio-2005, windows-vista

When install vs 2005 on windows vista it gives me the following error log .. what can I do??

```
***EndOfSession***[11/05/09,19:09:09] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InstallManagerHelper() with HRESULT -2147023295.
[11/05/09,19:09:09] setup.exe: [2] Component error string not specified in ISetupManager::AddToActionResultCollection()
[11/05/09,19:09:54] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition - ENU is not installed.
[11/05/09,19:09:54] VS70pgui: [2] Unknown component status forMicrosoft SQL Server 2005 Express Edition x86
[11/05/09,20:31:31] Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition - ENU: [2] ERROR:Error 1311.Source file not found: c:\users\mona\desktop\vs\_18659_RTL_x86_enu_VS2005ImageLibrary.cab.  Verify that the file exists and that you can access it.
[11/05/09,20:31:32] Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition - ENU: [2] ERROR:Error 1311.Source file not found: c:\users\mona\desktop\vs\_18659_RTL_x86_enu_VS2005ImageLibrary.cab.  Verify that the file exists and that you can access it.
[11/05/09,20:31:43] Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition - ENU: [2] ERROR:Error 1311.Source file not found: c:\users\mona\desktop\vs\_18659_RTL_x86_enu_VS2005ImageLibrary.cab.  Verify that the file exists and that you can access it.
[11/05/09,20:31:46] Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition - ENU: [2] ACTION FAILURE:Action ended 20:31:46: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.See MSI log for details.
[11/05/09,20:32:30] Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition - ENU: [2] ACTION FAILURE:Action ended 20:32:30: INSTALL. Return value 3.See MSI log for details.
[11/05/09,20:36:59] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InstallManagerHelper() with HRESULT -2147023293.
[11/05/09,20:36:59] setup.exe: [2] Component error string not specified in ISetupManager::AddToActionResultCollection()
[11/05/09,20:37:07] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition - ENU is not installed.
[11/05/09,20:37:07] VS70pgui: [2] Unknown component status forMicrosoft SQL Server 2005 Express Edition x86
[11/05/09,23:38:28] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InstallManagerHelper() with HRESULT -2147023295.
[11/05/09,23:38:28] setup.exe: [2] Component error string not specified in ISetupManager::AddToActionResultCollection()
***EndOfSession******EndOfSession***[11/05/09,19:09:09] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InstallManagerHelper() with HRESULT -2147023295.
[11/05/09,19:09:09] setup.exe: [2] Component error string not specified in ISetupManager::AddToActionResultCollection()
[11/05/09,19:09:54] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition - ENU is not installed.
[11/05/09,19:09:54] VS70pgui: [2] Unknown component status forMicrosoft SQL Server 2005 Express Edition x86
[11/05/09,20:31:31] Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition - ENU: [2] ERROR:Error 1311.Source file not found: c:\users\mona\desktop\vs\_18659_RTL_x86_enu_VS2005ImageLibrary.cab.  Verify that the file exists and that you can access it.
[11/05/09,20:31:32] Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition - ENU: [2] ERROR:Error 1311.Source file not found: c:\users\mona\desktop\vs\_18659_RTL_x86_enu_VS2005ImageLibrary.cab.  Verify that the file exists and that you can access it.
[11/05/09,20:31:43] Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition - ENU: [2] ERROR:Error 1311.Source file not found: c:\users\mona\desktop\vs\_18659_RTL_x86_enu_VS2005ImageLibrary.cab.  Verify that the file exists and that you can access it.
[11/05/09,20:31:46] Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition - ENU: [2] ACTION FAILURE:Action ended 20:31:46: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.See MSI log for details.
[11/05/09,20:32:30] Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition - ENU: [2] ACTION FAILURE:Action ended 20:32:30: INSTALL. Return value 3.See MSI log for details.
[11/05/09,20:36:59] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InstallManagerHelper() with HRESULT -2147023293.
[11/05/09,20:36:59] setup.exe: [2] Component error string not specified in ISetupManager::AddToActionResultCollection()
[11/05/09,20:37:07] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition - ENU is not installed.
[11/05/09,20:37:07] VS70pgui: [2] Unknown component status forMicrosoft SQL Server 2005 Express Edition x86
[11/05/09,23:38:28] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InstallManagerHelper() with HRESULT -2147023295.
[11/05/09,23:38:28] setup.exe: [2] Component error string not specified in ISetupManager::AddToActionResultCollection()
[11/05/09,23:38:36] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition - ENU is not installed.
[11/07/09,13:44:35] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InstallManagerHelper() with HRESULT -2147023295.
[11/07/09,13:44:35] setup.exe: [2] Component error string not specified in ISetupManager::AddToActionResultCollection()
***EndOfSession***
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you check whether this file exists? And can you open it?
`C:\Users\Mona\Desktop\vs_18659_RTL_x86_enu_VS2005ImageLibrary.cab`

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed Vista Service Pack 1? That's supposed to help with some VS issues. Also try copying the DVD to your hard disk and installing from there.